# Opening Qt Project After Relocating It

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I created a C++ Qt Creator CMake project. It worked perfectly when I loaded in to the program. However, when I copy pasted the project into another folder, it doesn't open in the Qt creator application anymore.

Instead of a Qt project, it just opens as a normal folder with CMakeLists.txt only while all other files are added separately. Is there no way I can copy the program as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove CMakeLists.txt.user when copying it to another folder. Then QtCreator will not open the old settings and creates a new build tree.